# Swift: assigning function to variable

Tags: swift

I have a class in swift with the following variable:

```
var pendingFunction = ((Double, Double) -> Double)
```

Swift then tells me:

> Expected member name or constructor call after type name

It insists that I change my code to:

```
var pendingFunction = ((Double, Double) -> Double).self
```

I have no clue what this `.self` thing is doing (sorry I'm new to Swift)

I then try to assign `pendingFunction` to a new function:

```
pendingFunction = function
```

where `function` takes two Doubles and returns a Double.

However, I'm presented with the following error:

> Cannot assign value of type '(Double,Double) -> Double' to type '((Double,Double)->Double).Type'

So my question is: what is the `.self` thing doing and how can I properly assign a function to the variable?

Comment: You'll want `var pendingFunction: ((Double, Double) -> Double)` to declare a variable of function type.

Comment: 'var pendingFunction: ((Double, Double) -> Double) = { firstDouble, secondDouble in /* do you stuff here*/ }' then call it 'let resultDouble = pendingFunction(double1, double2)'

Comment: As for .self, that means you're assigning the type of the function, rather than an actual function.  For example, `var someInt: Int` means you're going to assign a specific Int value to it, while `var someInt = Int.self` means you're using it to represent the Int type as a whole.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The postfix `.self` expression just refers to the object it's an instance of. Kind of like `.this` in other languages. For types in particular, it tells the compiler that you're referring to the type itself, rather than instructing it to create a new instance of that type. If you'd like to know more, you can read all about it in the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID455). While useful in a lot of cases, it's not really needed here.

As for your problem, when you assign:

```
var pendingFunction = ((Double, Double) -> Double).self
```

You're assigning the *type* of a particular sort of function as the *value* of the variable. From that, Swift infers that the *type* of the variable should be `Type`. Then later when you try to assign an actual function fitting that type as the value, it throws an error because it's expecting a type, not a function.

Instead of assigning a type as value, you want to declare the variable with that type as its type:

```
var pendingFunction: ((Double, Double) -> Double)
```

Here's an example of the whole thing:

```
var pendingFunction: ((Double, Double) -> Double)

func myAdditionFunction (first: Double, second: Double) -> Double {
    return first + second
}

pendingFunction = myAdditionFunction

print(pendingFunction(1,2)) // prints "3.0"
```

Comment: When I insert this line in the var class definition place I get a compiler error which appear on another innocent line. Xcode 11.3.

Comment: @DavidKramf It would help if you showed the error, the innocent line that's reporting it, and which line you inserted and where. You may need to post it as a new question.