# Assign method (function of an object) to a variable or how to pass a parameter to unit tests

Tags: swift, unit-testing

```
extension Array where Element == Int {
    
    mutating func bubbleSort() {
        let n = count
        guard n > 1 else { return }
        for i in 0 ..< n {
            var isSorted = true
            for j in 1 ..< n - i {
                if self[j - 1] > self[j] {
                    swapAt(j - 1, j)
                    isSorted = false
                }
            }
            if isSorted { break }
        }
    }
}

import XCTest //MARK: UnitTests

class SortingTest: XCTestCase {
    
    func testSorting1() {
        var a = [9, 2, 5, 3, 8, 1, 4, 7, 6]
        a.bubbleSort()
        XCTAssertEqual(a, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
    }
    
    func testSorting2() {
        var a = [4, 3, 2, 1]
        a.bubbleSort()
        XCTAssertEqual(a, [1, 2, 3, 4])
    }
    
    func testSorting3() {
        var a = [2, 1]
        a.bubbleSort()
        XCTAssertEqual(a, [1, 2])
    }
    
    //And many many more tests here
}

SortingTest.defaultTestSuite.run()
```

That's playground code of bubbleSort algorithm and it works totally fine.
But what if I implement one more sort algorithm:

```
extension Array where Element == Int {
    
    mutating func oneMoreSortAlg() {
        // Some algorithm code here
    }
    
    mutating func andEvenMoreSortAlg() {
        // Some more code here
    }
}
```

Obviously the test code will be almost the same for each algorithm. So I have to somehow pass which one I want to test now.
I'm new to Unit Testing so I don't know what is the canonical way to do this. I'll appreciate any hints.

And it raises one more question. Let's suppose I will decide to do it in this way (probably not canonical):

```
class SortingTest: XCTestCase {
    let customSort = Array.object.oneMoreSortAlg //it's defenetly a wrong syntax
    
    func testSorting1() {
        var a = [9, 2, 5, 3, 8, 1, 4, 7, 6]
        a.customSort() // or maybe customSort(a), I really don't know
        XCTAssertEqual(a, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
    }
    
    func testSorting2() {
        var a = [4, 3, 2, 1]
        a.customSort() // or maybe customSort(a), I really don't know
        XCTAssertEqual(a, [1, 2, 3, 4])
    }
    
    func testSorting3() {
        var a = [2, 1]
        a.customSort() // or maybe customSort(a), I really don't know
        XCTAssertEqual(a, [1, 2])
    }
    
    //And many many more tests here
}
```

I'm not new to swift but I've realised that I don't know how to correctly manage an assignment of method to a variable either.

Comment: Check [Swift assigning function to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43620100/swift-assigning-function-to-variable) for how to store a function as a closure variable. However, trying to do that with a `mutating func` will result in a compiler error of `Partial application of 'mutating' method is not allowed`, which I'm not sure can be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [It turns out that for each instance method a type has, there's a
> corresponding static method that lets you retrieve that instance
> method as a closure, by passing an instance as an argument.](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/first-class-functions-in-swift/)

For example: `[3, 2, 1].sort() == Array.sort([3, 2, 1])`
Interesting fact, but pretty useless in our case, because

> Partial application of 'mutating' method is not allowed.

So as long as I can't pass a mutating method as a parameter, I will pass an enumeration object:

```
extension Array where Element == Int {
    
    mutating func sort(_ algorithm: SortAlgorithm) {
        switch algorithm {
            case .bubble: bubbleSort()
            case .selection: selectionSort()
        }
    }
}

enum SortAlgorithm {
    case bubble
    case selection
}
```

As for second part of the question I think the best answer is inheritance:

```
// MARK: - Basic UnitTest Class

class SortingTest: XCTestCase {
    static var algorithm: SortAlgorithm!
    
    override static func tearDown() {
        algorithm = nil
        super.tearDown()
    }
    
    func testSorting1() {
        var a = [9, 2, 5, 3, 8, 1, 4, 7, 6]
        a.sort(Self.algorithm)
        XCTAssertEqual(a, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
    }
    
    func testSorting2() {
        var a = [4, 3, 2, 1]
        a.sort(Self.algorithm)
        XCTAssertEqual(a, [1, 2, 3, 4])
    }
    ......

// MARK: - Inherited UnitTest Classes

class BubbleTest: SortingTest {
    
    override static func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        algorithm = .bubble
    }
}

class SelectionTest: SortingTest {
    
    override static func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        algorithm = .selection
    }
}
```

Everything is ready for nicely calling tests for appropriate sorting algorithm:

```
extension enum SortAlgorithm {
    
    func runTests() {
        switch self {
            case .bubble: BubbleTest.defaultTestSuite.run()
            case .selection: SelectionTest.defaultTestSuite.run()
        }
    }
}

SortAlgorithm.bubble.runTests()
```

P.S. Thank @DávidPásztor and @matt for hints :)

Answer (score 0):

An instance method of a given instance is a first-class object. So you can just make a list of all the algorithms you want to try and try them in turn. Simplified example:

```
struct S {
    func alg1() -> String {
        return "hey"
    }

    func alg2() -> String {
        return "hey"
    }
}

func testBoth() {
    let s = S()
    let algs = [s.alg1, s.alg2] // <- this is the point
    for alg in algs {
        let result = alg()
        print(result)
    }
}
```

(But as Dávid Pásztor points out, you'll need to wrap your actual example code in such a way that you are not trying to make a list of mutating methods.)

Comment: That's not going to work with `mutating` funds though. It gives a compiler error of `Partial application of 'mutating' method is not allowed`.

Answer (score 0):

You can store a function in a variable by simply accessing the function, but not executing it (not writing the `()` after the method name).

Assign the result of the function: `let sorted: [Int] = [1,2,3].sorted()`

Assign the function: `let sort: () -> [Int] = [1,2,3].sorted`

However, you cannot store a mutating function in a variable, because that would result in the compiler error

> Partial application of 'mutating' method is not allowed

You can overcome this issue by wrapping all of your mutating funcs in non-mutating
functions and storing those non-mutating functions in your unit tests.

Create the non-mutating wrappers in your test target:

```
extension Array where Element == Int {
    func sortedByAlg1() -> [Element] {
        var copy = self
        copy.oneMoreSortAlg()
        return copy
    }

    func sortedByAlg2() -> [Element] {
        var copy = self
        copy.andEvenMoreSortAlg()
        return copy
    }
}
```

And then your test file:

```
class TestSortingAlgos: XCTestCase {
    // Initialise this to the values you want to input to your sorting functions
    // If you want to use several sets of I/O pairs, simply change these two arrays to be nested arrays ([[Int]]())
    var input = [Int]()
    /// Initialise this to the expected outputs for your input
    var output = [Int]()

    func testAllSorts() {
        let sortingFuncs = [input.sortedByAlg1, input.sortedByAlg2]
        for sortingFunc in sortingFuncs {
            // Beware that `sortingFunc` here is executed on the array you used in the `sortingFuncs` declaration (`input`) for our case - if you wanted to iterate over an array of inputs, you'd need to create an outer loop and assing `sortingFuncs` there.
            XCTAssertEqual(sortingFunc(),output)
        }
    }
}
```